# Polymer paper-card profile picture

Tags: polymer, material-design

Is it possible to include a round thumbnail in the paper-card element following the material design card specification on https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-actions ?

The webcomponents.org documentation only showcases a fullscreen image implemented via `<paper-card image="demo/donuts.png">`, I however would like to implement something like

[image]

Is this possible with the paper-card Polymer 2 element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `paper-icon-item` inside `paper-card`.

```
<paper-card heading="Emmental">
  <div class="card-content">
    <!-- Paper icon item starts here -->
    <paper-icon-item>
      <div class="avatar blue" slot="item-icon"></div>
      <paper-item-body two-line>
        <div>Alphonso Engelking</div>
        <div secondary>Change photo</div>
      </paper-item-body>
    </paper-icon-item>
    <!-- Paper icon item ends -->
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions">
    <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
    <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Hope this helps :)